# How to view all iTunes backups and respective devices?

Tags: itunes, backup

There are a bunch of backups in the folder:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup
```

However, they're all named gibberish and difficult to identify. This folder takes up 30% of the space on my 500 GB hard drive.

How do I find out what device they're for, along with their date, so I can decide which to delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferences > Devices will show all backups, from which you can delete specific versions.
On Windows, hit  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  to show the menu bar at the top.

This pic from Mac, but should be very similar...

[image]